# GitLab API How to find branch name for specific commit

Tags: git, api, gitlab, branch

I'm trying to find connection between tag and branch name.
Using this:

`GET v4/projects/:id/repository/tags?page=1&per_page=1`

I get last tag and commit id. I need to find branch name with specific commit.
How to get branch with specific commit id? I've tried "

`GET v4/projects/:id/repository/commits/:short_id`  - but there isn't branch name in commit

`v4/projects/id:/repository/branches?short_id="specific_id` - returns all branches :(

All this because I need to pull  local and then push to remote specific TAG

Comment: If there is no branch attached to that specific commit, at most you will be able to find out which branches the commit is reachable on, can you elaborate on which branch in particular you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe [`/projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha/refs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-references-a-commit-is-pushed-to)?

Comment: let's say I have 3 branches R_1.0, R_2.0 and R_3.0. Someone pushed new TAG 3.0. I need to find commit which is connected to this TAG and then BRANCH name because I need to pull this branch to local repository and then push to remote repository. It's all about pushing TAGs between two remotes repositories

Comment: @Amadan it could be handy thanks

Comment: @Amadan is it possible to get only specific types refs? 
 /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha/refs returns branch and tag is there something like this:
/projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha/refs?type=branch

Comment: Yes, `type=branch` as a parameter is explicitly mentioned in the docs I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

> let's say I have 3 branches R_1.0, R_2.0 and R_3.0. Someone pushed new TAG 3.0. I need to find commit which is connected to this TAG and then BRANCH name ...

There may not be one.  A tag can name a commit that is not reachable by *any* branch name.

> ... because I need to pull this branch to local repository and then push to remote repository. It's all about pushing TAGs between two remotes repositories ...

If you simply want to get the tag $T and its tagged commit from remote $r1 to remote $r2, via your local repository, you need not go through all this kind of craziness.  Just do:

```
die() {
    echo "fatal: $@"
    exit 1
}
# e.g., r1=origin and r2=upstream, T=v1.2

# obtain the specific tagged commit and its history, using the
# same tag name locally, from remote r1
git fetch $r1 refs/tags/$T:refs/tags/$T || die "fetch from $r1 failed"

# then send that commit and the tag name to remote r2
git push $r2 refs/tags/$T:refs/tags/$T || die "push to $r2 failed"
```

(Note that the above script is not tested.)